# Was heißt Plattfuß im Titel der bekannten Filmreihe?

Tags: meaning-in-context, etymology

***[Sie nannten Ihn Plattfuß](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sie_nannten_ihn_Plattfu%C3%9F)*** mit Bud Spencer als Commissario Manuele Rizzo heißt im italienischen Original ***Piedone lo sbirro***. Dabei ist *piedóne* Augment von *piede* "Fuß", während *sbirro* wohl ein Euphemismus ist wie Cop oder Bulle. Auf English heißt der Film entsprechend *Flatfoot*, was wohl ebenfalls ein Euphemismus ist:

> 3. (*colloquial, archaic, derogatory, law enforcement*) *(plural typically flatfoots)* A policeman.

> 4. (*US, informal, military, slang*) A sailor.

Grimms Deutsches Wörterbuch kennt zumindest noch "nautisch nach holländischem *platvoet* die wache am bord des schiffes von 6 bis 8 uhr abends. Bobrik 531ᵇ." (DWB: "plattfusz")

Laut lateinischer Wörterbücher ist planipes "flatfood, barefoot" auch eine Bezeichnung für eine Art Schauspieler, aber mit wechselnder Bedeutung. *Pedes* selbst kann Fußsoldat bedeuten.

Ist der deutsche Titel eine weniger literarische Übersetzung des englischen oder ist diese Bedeutung hierzulande auch (irgendwo) bekannt oder ist etwas ganz anderes gemeint gewesen?

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sbirro

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/piede#Italian

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flatfoot

https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/plattfusz

Comment: Wenn überhaupt, ist der deutsche Titel eine Übersetzung aus dem Italienischen - Denn es ist ja ein italienischer Film. Siehe meine Antwort.

Comment: Aus dem verlinkten Artikel zu "Plattfusz" in Grimm's Wörterbuch erschien dir die Bedeutung "ein grober (breit und derb auftretender) mensch, flegel" gar nicht erwähnenswert?

Answer (score 2):

Als [Plattfuß](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plattfu%C3%9F) bezeichnet man (neben anderen Bedeutungen) eine "angeborene oder erworbene Fußfehlstellung", die unter anderem von Übergewicht verursacht werden kann. Bei vielen der Figuren, die Bud Spencer gespielt hat, wurde ja sein Gewicht betont. Man könnte sagen, Commissario Rizzo hat sich mit seinem Gewicht die Füße platt gelaufen.

Answer (score 1):

*Plattfuß* ist die wörtliche Übersetzung des italienischen *piedipiatti*, was im gleichen (leicht abfälligen) Kontext bei uns "Bulle" heißt. Der Titelübersetzer hat also vor Phatasie nicht gerade gesprüht...

Und, ja, wahrscheinlich heißen im Italienischen die Polizisten "Plattfüße" weil sie sich beim Streifegehen ebensolche holen. Eine Anspielung auf das Gewicht ist das aber nicht. Auch die mageren Polizisten werden in Italien so genannt.

Comment: Vgl.  "Skandal im Sperrbezirk"

Comment: Wahrscheinlich nicht, denn "piatti" als Abwandlung von "palazo", "palatium", "paladin" oder so wäre mindestens genauso wahrscheinlich wie eine itliänsche Form des germanischen Wortes "platt" (die ich unterdessen nicht bestreite) ... vielleicht ein ippolit zu fuß, wer weiß, darum ging es nicht. Es ging auch nicht um eine unterschwellige Bewertung des Machwerks.

Comment: wahrscheinlich was nicht? Übrigens ist "platt" nicht sehr germanisch, sondern vom lateinischen "plattus" abgeleitet (und das wiederum aus dem Griechischen)

Comment: @vectory: "piat-ti" ist unschwer als Zusammensetzung des Yoruba-Worts "pa á (ausschalten, töten) mit dem sumerischen "ti" (Pfeil) zu erkennen. Möglich wäre auch altägyptisch "pat" (Adelsgeschlecht, Oberschicht) oder die Herleitung aus "pitya-", was "gehen" in Pitjantjatjara bedeutet.